# Copy Task in YAML

Tags: yaml

I have YAML file with some tasks to copy files from a source folder to a target folder:

```
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'copy file 1'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: SourceFolder
        Contents: 'File1' 
        TargetFolder: TargetFolder

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'copy file 2'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: SourceFolder
        Contents: 'File2' 
        TargetFolder: TargetFolder

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'copy file 3'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: SourceFolder
        Contents: 'File3' 
        TargetFolder: TargetFolder
```

How do I replace the above tasks with only 1 task to copy file 1, file 2, file 3 from SourceFolder to TargetFolder? I tried using * and ** but these don't work as files are located different folders within SourceFolder.

Answer (score 1):

Update Answer:

I think this might work with multiple files:

```
contents:
      ?(File1|File2|File3)
```

======================================

There are sample YAML from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Did you tried with

```
contents: '**'
```

Comment: Thank you! As I mentioned in my question, I tried ** but ** it copies all files in the specified source folder and all files in all sub-folders I only need to copy some files from the source folder